# How to map two arrays based on comparative value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two arrays:

A sequential array of numbers between 1-8, in increments of 1:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

A sequential array of numbers between 1-8, with random increments:

```
b = [1,2,5,7]
```

I want to create a list of `{a:val, b:val}` dict pairs, where the value of `b` is only the next in the array if it is equal or greater to the value of `a`:

```
c = [
       {a:1, b:1}, 
       {a:2, b:2}, 
       {a:3, b:2}, 
       {a:4, b:2}, 
       {a:5, b:5}, 
       {a:6, b:5}, 
       {a:7, b:7}, 
       {a:8, b:7}
   ]
```

Is there an easy way to do this? I thought about using compounding `$.each` loops to build new arrays and increment values, but it seems as though this is overkill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` and `shift`

- Loop over first array.
- If the value of current element is greater then first element on second  array remove first element from second array, ( except when the length is less then 2)
- return object in desired format

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
let b = [1, 2, 5, 7]

let final = a.map(v => {
  if (v >= b[1] && b.length > 1) {
    b.shift()
  }
  return {
    a: v,
    b: b[0]
  }
})

console.log(final)
```

This mutates second array if you don't want to mutate you can use a index variable and increment it based on condition

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
let b = [1, 2, 5, 7]
let index = 0
let final = a.map(v => {
  if (v >= b[index+1] && b.length - 1 > index ) {
    index++
  }
  return {
    a: v,
    b: b[index]
  }
})

console.log(final)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. However the result in your example produces   `{"a": 3,"v": 5}`, whereas I am after `v` only incrementing if `b` is greater or equal to the value of `a`. I.e. 
 `{a:3, b:2}` in this case?

Comment: @alias51 you just need a minor change in if condition, just compare next index value instead of current index

Answer (score 0):

The first array is actually redundant - the only significant information it carries is the number of elements.

The following code determines the difference between 2 adjacent threshold values from array `b`. This is 1 less the number of array elements with object property `b` set to the lower of these threshold values.

The target array is constructed as the array of object properties `b` in proper order. The resulting value list is mapped to the desired format.

The code may be optimized. It should run fast if the length of array `b` is much less than the length of array `a`. This hypothesis is not tested though and given the low complexity of the code/data structures will probably be insignificant.

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
  , b = [1, 2, 5, 7]
  , c = []
  , n_last = 1
  ;

b.forEach ( (pn_current, pn_idx) => {
    c.push( ...((new Array(pn_current - n_last)).fill(n_last)) );
    n_last = pn_current;
});
c.push( ...((new Array(a.length + 1 - n_last)).fill(n_last)) );

c = c.map ( ( pn_entry, pn_idx ) => { return { a: pn_idx+1, b: pn_entry }; } );

console.log(c);
```